# How can I stack fixed navigation bars?

Tags: html, css

[Reference blog here](http://www.finesttest.blogspot.com/)
I'd like to set up two fixed navigation bars. However, when the first navigation bar meets the second, instead of the lower one "sticking" to the upper, it gets overwritten. How can I make it to where the bottom one attaches to the top?

Sorry, no fiddle for this, my reference blog will have to do.

Also, would it be possible for the logo to stay fixed and have the body continue to scroll? Thanks in advance!

Here's the source for the black navbar (stickhead tells that part to be sticky):

```
<!-- Top Nav Started -->
    <stickhead> 
        <div id='topnav'>
        <div class='wrapnya'>

<!-- Top Nav Clock -->
            <span class='tgltop'>
                    <i class='fa fa-clock-o'/> <span id='tglxnya'/>
                        <span id='clockx'/>
                            <script class='jshilang' type='text/javascript'>datetime();</script>    
            </span>
<!-- /Top Nav Clock -->

<!-- Top Nav Menu -->
            <a href='#' id='topmobilenav'>Menu</a>

            <ul class='sf-menu' id='topmenunav'>
              <li><a href='/p/about.html'>About</a></li>
                <li><a href='/p/contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href='/p/submit.html'>Submit</a></li>
            </ul>
<!-- /Top Nav Menu -->

<!-- Top Nav Socials -->
            <ul class='sociico socialmedia' id='icon-socialmn'>
              <li><a href='https://facebook.com/thefinestnews' target='_blank'>Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href='https://twitter.com/TheFinestNews' target='_blank'>Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href='https://plus.google.com/+FinestnewsBlogspotOfficial/' target='_blank'>Google+</a></li>
                <li><a href='/feeds/posts/default' target='_blank'>RSS</a></li>
            </ul>
<!-- /Top Nav Social -->
      </div>
    </div>
    </stickhead>
```

Here's the source for the red navbar (sticknav tells that part to be sticky):

```
<!-- Main Nav Started -->
   <nav class='navix' id='nav'>
   <sticknav>   
        <div class='wrap'>      

<!-- Main Nav Menu -->
        <a href='#' id='mobilenav'>Menu</a>
        <ul class='sf-menu' id='menunav'>
            <li><a class='home' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'><b>FN</b></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='/p/about.html'>About</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/p/contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/p/submit.html'>Submit</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/p/dev.html'>Development</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='/search/label/Science'>Science</a></li>
            <li><a href='/search/label/Technology'>Technology</a></li>
            <li><a href='/search/label/Entertainment'>Entertainment</a></li>
            <li><a href='/search/label/Business'>Business</a></li>
            <li><a href='/search/label/Politics'>Politics</a></li>
            <li><a href='/search/label/Local'>Local</a></li>
            <li><a href='/search/label/Sports'>Sports</a></li>
            <li><a href='/search/label/Life'>Life</a></li>
        </ul>
<!-- /Main Nav Menu -->

<!-- Main Nav Search -->
        <div id='searchnya'>
            <form action='/search' id='ajax-search-form'>
                <input name='q' onblur='if (this.value == &quot;&quot;) {this.value = &quot;Search articles...&quot;;}' onfocus='if (this.value == &quot;Search articles...&quot;) {this.value = &quot;&quot;;}' type='text' value='Search articles...'/>
                <button title='Search' type='submit'>Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
<!-- /Main Nav Search -->

</div>
</sticknav>  

sticknav {
background: #b50000;
height: 46px;
width: 1080px;
margin: auto;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
border-top: 4px solid #e50000;
webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.49);
box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.49);
}
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
}
```

Here's the JS for both (JS for the red navbar is on top, there's probably a way to include both of these in one JS code but I was lazy):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var aboveHeight = 200;

$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= aboveHeight){
$('sticknav').addClass('fixed').css('top','0').next().css('padding-top','50px');
        } else {
       $('sticknav').removeClass('fixed').next().css('padding-top','0');
        }
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {

var aboveHeight = 25;

$(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= aboveHeight){
        $('stickhead').addClass('head').css('top','0').next().css('padding-top','29px');
        } else {
       $('stickhead').removeClass('head').next().css('padding-top','0');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what browser(s) are you having problems with??

Comment: I'm pretty sure I just don't have it set up correctly.

Comment: didn't understand your question properly. do you want to stack both nav bars? one up and the other down of it? if so, then which nav bar you want on top? the red one or the black one?

Comment: Black one. In the order which you scroll down. For example, the black one will become fixed before the red one because that's how it happens when you scroll down.

Comment: I just had another look, the navbars are fine on google chrome, and IE 11. and for mobiles you dont seem to have the meta tag (<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">) anyway to scale it to mobile

Comment: Yeah, I know they work but they aren't stacking. Also, the mobile template is broken for some reason but that's for another day.

Comment: okay now i've understood properly, i'm going to get my hair cut, after that I'll come and try to fix your problem.. :) ;)

Comment: have you disabled the top menu to be sticky? I'm opening your blog now and I see your main menu (red) is sticky but not the black one.
And it will be easy for us if you can provide your source code for the two navs..

Comment: Oh yeah, oops. I'll fix that and add the HTML later today.

Comment: Alright, it's fixed. Give me a few seconds to post the source.

Comment: Any news? It's not urgent, just wondering if progress has been made.